# Error in Stored Procedure Performing Inserts in While Loop

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure to delete users from a table and add them back with all the correct criteria. This will be run on a daily basis when I get it running correctly. We have a table of companies and a table of users. The companies table changes as well as the users table. For a certain group of users, they should have permissions to all companies and exist in the table user_company. The permissions to individual companies have to be granted manually. Often companies or users are added and we are not notified to add them to the user_company table. This process will automate this process. The table was initially set up by someone else and will allow duplicate entries of user_id and company_id. In order to keep that cleaned up, I want to delete all users with a certain email address and then add them back for every active company. For the development phase, I am only working with two users. When it's proven out to be working, I will modify the two defined users to users with emails like %@xxx.com.

In this procedure, I am deleting the specific users from the user_company table so there are no xxx.com users there. Then I want to take a list of all current active companies and a list of all current active xxx.com email addresses and insert one row for each combination of user and company.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin_dev`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_grant_user_companies`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int;
    DECLARE compcount int;
    DECLARE minuser int;
    DECLARE mincomp int;

    DELETE FROM user_company WHERE user_id IN(1113,1153);
    DELETE FROM user_facility WHERE user_id IN(1113,1153);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE companies;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE companies
    SELECT integration_id, 0 AS inserted_company FROM ems_admin_dev.company WHERE name NOT LIKE 'zz%' ORDER BY integration_id
    LIMIT 0;
    insert INTO companies SELECT integration_id, 0 AS inserted_company FROM admin_dev.company WHERE name NOT LIKE 'zz%' ORDER BY integration_id;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE users;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users
    SELECT id, username, 0 AS INSERTED_USER FROM admin_dev.user WHERE username IN('ca.ro@xxx.com','ca.co@xxx.com')  
    AND status='ACTIVE' AND is_deleted=0 ORDER BY username
    LIMIT 0;
    INSERT INTO users 
    SELECT id, username, 0 AS INSERTED_USER 
    FROM admin_dev.user WHERE username IN('ca.ro@xxx.com','ca.co@xxx.com') 
    AND status='ACTIVE' 
    AND is_deleted=0 ORDER BY username;

    #begin_user_company_inserts
    SET i = 1;
    SET compcount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM companies);
    SET minuser = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM users WHERE INSERTED_USER=0);
    SET mincomp = (SELECT MIN(integration_id) FROM companies WHERE INSERTED_COMPANY=0);

    WHILE i <= compcount DO
    INSERT INTO user_company (user_id, company_id)
    SELECT minuser, mincomp;
    SET i = i + 1;
    UPDATE companies SET INSERTED_COMPANY=1 WHERE integration_id=mincomp;
    UPDATE users SET INSERTED_USER=1 WHERE id=minuser;
    SET minuser = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM users WHERE INSERTED_USER=0);
    SET mincomp = (SELECT MIN(integration_id) FROM companies WHERE INSERTED_COMPANY=0);
#end_user_company_inserts

    END WHILE;
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure, I'm getting this error:
*Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ems_admin_dev`.`user_company`, CONSTRAINT `FK_user_company_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))*

I am deleting the users from user_company before I try to add them back again, so I don't know how the foreign key is preventing it. I have verified the rows are getting deleted, but the new ones are not getting added back.

Answer (score 0):

What is the database name where the stored procedure resides in? You are using tables `admin_dev.user` and plain (no database named) `user_company` where `user_company` has foreign key to, again plain, `user` table.

Do not see anything in the procedure which would require a loop, you could do it as normal set operations with couple of queries.

Also, the loop itself looks bit dangerous as it expects that there is no other activity in the database when the procedure is run (hint: someone can add another company during the procedure run).

Comment: Ok I tried adding the schema name in all the places where the actual tables are listed. I also renamed the temporary tables so it's more obvious which ones are temp tables and which ones are actual tables. I still get the same error. 

I can't paste the new contents of the stored procedure below - says it's too long. If there is an easier way to do this than what I'm attempting here, I'll all for learning something new.

Comment: I can see that it is inserting one record for each user, for different companies. Then it stops. In theory, the way it should work is grab the first user and insert one row for every company for that user, then move to the next user and insert one row for every company for that user, and so on. 1113 3 1153 11 That's all it's inserting before it stops. The primary key is an ID field and the only foreign key is for user and the users do exist in the user table.